# Universal File Duplicator

Tags: c++, file, console

I made a simple Universal-File-Duplicator (Example: make 125 duplicates of one file).
Very useful if you want to fill a whole USB flash drive or an old harddisk with an important file (Example: Bitcoin wallet.dat or privatekey) and you don't want to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> all the time...

Suggestions? Improvements?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char nummer[1000000], sourcefile[255], targetfile[255], targetfileneu[255], endung[255];
    int i = 0;
    int anzahl = 0;
    ifstream Quelldatei;

    printf("Welcome! You are using UNIVERSAL-DATEI-DUPLIKATOR v1.0\n");
    printf("Filename? (Example: test.txt)\n");
    gets(sourcefile);
    printf("New Filename without ending? (Example: filename)\n");
    gets(targetfile);
    printf("Ending? (Example: .txt)\n");
    gets(endung);

    printf("How many times do you want to create the file?\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &anzahl);

    for (i = 0; i < anzahl; i++)
    {
        sprintf(nummer, "%ld", i);
        strcpy(targetfileneu, targetfile);
        strcat(targetfileneu, nummer);
        strcat(targetfileneu, endung);
        printf("Targetfilename: %s\n", targetfileneu);

        Quelldatei.open(sourcefile, ios::binary);
        if (!Quelldatei)
        {
            cerr << "ERROR!\n";
            return 0;
        }                                    
        ofstream Zieldatei(targetfileneu, ios::binary);
        if (!Zieldatei)
        {
            cerr << "ERROR!\n";
                    return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int c; 
        while ((c = Quelldatei.get()) >= 0) { Zieldatei.put(c); }
        }
        memset(&targetfileneu[0], 0, sizeof(targetfileneu));
        Quelldatei.close();
        Zieldatei.close();
    }
    printf("SUCCESS!\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to fill a whole harddisk with one file? If the drive crashes, it crashes. Even though this could be useful for when only some sectors of a drive goes down, making copies across multiple drives would be more reasonable.

Comment: I'm no expert but I think it's better to have the file on all platters for longterm storage (10+ years). If the one platter gets damaged (due to a magnetic field for example) the chances are higher that you can restore the file from another platter.
I think it is even possible to restore the file if there is only a fragment of a platter intact.

Comment: @Thomas: That is why RAID was invented. Reformat your drive with RAID 10 http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/raid-levels-tutorial/

Comment: I know, but RAID is not possible with very old and different IDE harddisks :)

Comment: Why write a (extremely buggy and inefficient) C++ program for something you could do with a single, short shell one-liner?

Comment: Do you mean a batch-program? I don't know how to make this..
Maybe you can post the batch-code as an alternative here?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a `using namespace std;` in your code. [Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace). ([No, really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

---

[`gets` is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used); don't use it. Streams are so much more convenient anyway! For instance, you could write:

```
std::string sourcefile, targetfile, endung;
std::cout << "Welcome! You are using UNIVERSAL-DATEI-DUPLIKATOR v1.0\n"
          << "Filename? (Example: test.txt)\n";
std::cin >> sourcefile;
std::cout << "New Filename without ending? (Example: filename)\n";
std::cin >> targetfile;
std::cout << "Ending? (Example: .txt)\n";
std::cin >> endung;

int anzahl;
std::cout << "How many times do you want to create the file?\n";
std::cin >> anzahl;
```

---

Opening the input file only once and resetting the stream to the beginning for each copy may allow the stream to make better use of buffering, reducing the number of seeks required.

Also, streams can be copied directly to `streambuf`s using `operator>>`.

```
std::ifstream Quelldatei(sourcefile, std::ios::binary);
for (int i = 0; i < anzahl; ++i) {
    Quelldatei.seekg(0);
    std::ostringstream output_filename(targetfile);
    output_filename << i << endung;
    std::ofstream Zieldatei(output_filename, std::ios::binary);
    Quelldatei >> Zieldatei.rdbuf();
    Zieldatei.close();
}
std::cout << "SUCCESS!" << std::endl;
system("pause");
```